# How make array inside left join condition using CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to have an array inside left join condition?
because I've 3 conditions inside one table name

example:

This is example how my code works

```
->join('table as t1','condition here','left')
->join('table as t2','condition here','left')
->join('table as t3','condition here','left')
```

but I want to make it easy and avoid redundantion, is it posible to have array inside join?

```
->join('table_name',array(),'left');
```

Any Ideas would be appreciated

Comment: join only take two column values with same data types

Comment: Why many table join to 1 table ?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use it like below

```
$this->db->from('table as t');
$this->db->join('table as t1','t1.coloum1 = t.coloum1 AND t1.coloum2 = t.coloum2 AND t1.coloum3 = t.coloum3','left')
```